# AVCaptureConnection Freezes my app on the second call

Tags: iphone, ios

this is my code that freezes my app

```
 AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported] )
{
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];

}
```

this is my videoOutput init

```
// Setup video capture
videoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice: front? frontVideoDevice: rearVideoDevice error: &error] retain];
videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[videoOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames: YES];
// Set the video output to store frame in BGRA (It is supposed to be faster)
NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]; 
NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key]; 
[videoOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];
```

when I initialize the session in the second time my app stop responding
but if i remove the code of the avcaptureconnection everything is fine

?

Comment: i assume it is a memory management problem. can you check via the debugger that there is a valid object `videoOutput` the second time you try to call it? can you post the exact error message please?

Comment: I get not error that's the issue, and the videoOutput is properly allocated. but now i notice that i get the AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification.

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint ?

Answer (score 0):

...!

I called 
`[session startRunning]` 
before the

```
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];


if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported] )
{
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait];

}
```

my bad :)